# Automatic/Tool Visualize Database Schema

Tags: sql, database, sybase, erd

It's recently fallen upon the shoulders of another developer and I to pull information from a database spanning some 669 tables with no useful documentation or accessible experts/DBAs of the database. We're not even exactly sure what all information is locked away in the tables that we can pull from to create our--effectively--reports.

Is there any tool or method of generating a diagram (or any other way) to visualize the information to speed up the process?

I was thinking about a generic SQL tool, but the specific database technology is Sybase.

Comment: Good luck! I like http://schemaspy.sourceforge.net/ to extract basic information.

Comment: Which Sybase product specifically?

Comment: Sorry Michael. I didn't see your comment earlier. The product is Cisco Prime LAN Management, which our Cisco Prime guy described as a--paraphrasing--distorted, strange modified Sybase database.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Sybase Powerdesigner for reverse-engineering database schemas some years ago. I used it to generate a database diagram of the tables with foreign keys to show the relation between the tables. It supports other databases than Sybase too.

Comment: My coworker is looking into this and Schemaspy. Thanks for the input, and I'll be sure to mark as the answer if it works out for him!